# $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k x^k \underset{x \to 1^-}\rightarrow \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

- $\forall k, c_k \geq 0$
- $\sum c_k x^k$ has a radius of convergence $1$
- $\sum c_k =+\infty$

We want to show that $\sum_{k \geq 0} c_k x^k \underset{x \to 1^-}\rightarrow \infty $

---

My attempt :

Is it is correct ? There are several dependencies. Besides is there a shorter way ?

$
\begin{align*}
N &>0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^N c_k &= \sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x^k) + \sum_{k=1}^N c_k x^k \\
\sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x^k)&= \sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x) k \eta_x^{k-1} \\
\sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x^k)&\leq \sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x) k \\
x > 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k} > 1 - \dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} k c_k} &\implies\sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x) k \leq 1   \\
\end{align*}
$

- We choose $A >0$
- We choose $N$ such that $A < \sum_{k=1}^N c_k$
- We choose $x\in ] 1 - \eta, 1[$ such that $ x  > 1- \dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^N  c_k} > 1-\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^N k c_k} $
- It is possible because $\sum c_k$ diverges

$
\begin{align*}
A &< \sum_{k=1}^N c_k \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x^k) + \sum_{k=1}^N c_k x^k \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^N c_k (1-x) k + \sum_{k=1}^N c_k x^k \\
&\leq 1+ \sum_{k=1}^N c_k x^k \\
&\leq 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} c_k x^k \\
\end{align*}
$

Therefore, $\forall A>0, \exists \eta, x \in ]1- \eta, 1[ \implies A< \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} c_k x^k $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence is unnecessary. You can use the monotone convergence theorem. Consider the infinite power series. Each term is positive and as x approaches one from the bottom each term increases, so you can swap the sum and the limit. This, the series approaches infinity (or is always infinity) as x approaches $1^-$ iff the sum of the coefficients diverge.